# On Ajax Post, getting a bad request(404)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Using Ajax Post, getting a **Bad Request(404)**.

I tried to google but didn't help me in that.
Note: on using  `"contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',"` on post my request going as a `OPTIONS`

```js
var data = JSON.stringify(dataArr);
var clientType = $("#clientType").val();
var username = $("#hidUsername").val();
var clientId = $("#clientId").val();
var apiUrl = 'http://localhost.com/WebAPI/client/PostToclient'
$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  type: 'POST',
  //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',             
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    'clientData': data,
    'username': username,
    'Id': clientId,
    'clientType': clientType
  }),
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);

  },
  complete: function() {

  },
  error: function(ex) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Hello Harman Sharma, Have you tried same api call in postman is it working? Have you debugged api endpoin.?

Comment: Hey Harman, the Bad Request error usually has to do with something server side. Could you show us the code of your endpoint?

Comment: You might be getting something in your error log file. If you could share that, might be it will be better to understand. Also, what sort of data you are having dataArr, that's also a question, needs clarification.

Comment: Either PostToClient method is not available or method parameters not matching with your PostToClient method in API. Check that too.

Comment: `http://localhost.com/WebAPI/client/PostToclient` is probably a folder, in your case. Tack the file with an extension on there.

Comment: Hi, I tried to call my api using postman, but getting "Endpoint not found".
My Api methods:

 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/client/PostToclient/{clientData}/{username}/{Id}/{clientType}}", Method = "POST")]
 [OperationContract]
 public async Task<string> PostToclient(string clientData, string username, string Id, string clientType)
 {
  // Create / update client data.
 }

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your API its fairly hard to tell what going wrong. You will need to provide more information on the server side for this one ;)

One thing looks weird: the id field written in upper case 'Id', which likely to be 'id or 'clientId' if your API follow any kind of logic :p

Comment: Hi Ji aSH, 

My Api methods:
'
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/client/PostToclient/{clientData}/{username}/{Id}/{clientType}}", Method = "POST")]
 [OperationContract]
 public async Task<string> PostToclient(string clientData, string username, string Id, string clientType)
 {
  // Create / update client data.
 } '

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your API is working fine, for that you can test with postman app.
And I observed that **you are passing JSON content in a JSON data**. i.e client Data, I think it may not work.

Please try to declare client Data properties with primary json format, so that it may solve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for ur help.

I found the problem why its is not able to call api. Now I am able to post my data using ajax call.

```
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/client/PostToclient", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
  [OperationContract]
   public async Task<string> PostToclient(string clientData, string username, string Id, string clientType)
   {
   // Create / update client data.
   }
```